# Equivalence of inequalities involving the sum-of-divisors function

Tags: inequality, divisor-sum

Let $s(n)$ denote the sum of the proper divisors of $n$. For example, $s(6)=1+2+3=6$.

In 1976, [Erdős claimed that](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1976-30-135/S0025-5718-1976-0404115-8/S0025-5718-1976-0404115-8.pdf) (top of page 642) for every $k$ and $\delta>0$ and for all $n$ except a sequence of density $0$, it is true that $$(1-\delta)n\left(\frac{s(n)}{n}\right)^i<s^i(n)<(1+\delta)n\left(\frac{s(n)}{n}\right)^i\text{ for every }1\leqslant i\leqslant k.$$ However, only the first inequality was proven.

In 1990, [Erdős retracted his claim that](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/iterate.pdf) (middle of page 169) for every $k$ and $\epsilon>0$ and for all $n$ except a sequence of density $0$, it is true that $$\left|\frac{s(n)}{n}-\frac{s^{j+1}(n)}{s^j(n)}\right|<\epsilon\text{ for every }1\leqslant j\leqslant k.$$

I conclude that these inequalities are supposed to be equivalent, but I cannot show that this is the case. Are these inequalities equivalent?

Comment: Which inequalities are supposed to be equivalent?

Comment: @FluidizedPigeonReactor $(1-\delta)n\left(\frac{s(n)}{n}\right)^i<s^i(n)<(1+\delta)n\left(\frac{s(n)}{n}\right)^i$ and $\left|\frac{s(n)}{n}-\frac{s^{j+1}(n)}{s^j(n)}\right|<\epsilon$

Comment: what processes did you use to conclude that they are equivalent?